# Change a Word to a Different Color

Tags: javascript, text, colors

So I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("randoBtn").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = "Try writing a " + selectedWord() + " and";
    var selectWord  
    document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = selectedWord() + " story";
}

function selectedWord(){
    var myarray = new Array("Action", "Adventure", "Apocalyptic", "Comedy", "Detective", "Disaster", "Drama", "Epic", "Erotica", "Fable", "Fairy Tale", "Fantasy", "Fiction", "Folk Tale", "Ghost", "Historical", "Horror", "Humor", "Military", "Mystery", "Mythology", "Narrative", "Parallel Universe", "Paranormal", "Parody", "Poetry", "Post-Apocalyptic", "Pulp Fiction", "Quest", "Realistic Fiction", "Revenge", "Romantic", "Science Fiction", "Short Story", "Spy", "Supernatural", "Tall Tale", "Thriller", "Time Travel", "Undersea", "Western");

    return myarray[Math.round(Math.random() * (myarray.length - 1))];
}   
</script>
```

Is there anyway to change just the selectWord() variable to a different color? I just want it to stand out against the rest of the text. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have wrapped the selectedWord return with a  `<span>` tag, given that span a class name and styled the class name.

```js
function clickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("message1").innerHTML = "Try writing a <span class=\"Words\">" + selectedWord() + "</span> and";
    var selectWord  
    document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = "<span class=\"Words\">"+selectedWord() + "</span> story";
}
function selectedWord(){
    var myarray = new Array("Action", "Adventure", "Apocalyptic", "Comedy", "Detective", "Disaster", "Drama", "Epic", "Erotica", "Fable", "Fairy Tale", "Fantasy", "Fiction", "Folk Tale", "Ghost", "Historical", "Horror", "Humor", "Military", "Mystery", "Mythology", "Narrative", "Parallel Universe", "Paranormal", "Parody", "Poetry", "Post-Apocalyptic", "Pulp Fiction", "Quest", "Realistic Fiction", "Revenge", "Romantic", "Science Fiction", "Short Story", "Spy", "Supernatural", "Tall Tale", "Thriller", "Time Travel", "Undersea", "Western");

    return myarray[Math.round(Math.random() * (myarray.length - 1))];
}  
window.onload=function(){document.getElementById("randoBtn").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);}
```

```css
.Words{color:red;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
    <button id="randoBtn">Go!</button>
<div id="message1"></div>
<div id="message2"></div>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!